# Setting the foreground resource programmatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, foreground

I have created a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/LayoutProfit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    android:minWidth="0px"
    android:minHeight="50px"
    android:background="#edf0f4"
    android:foreground="@drawable/list_divider_full">
```

Now I want to change the foreground resource programmatically, but I don't know how. I can change the background resource like this:

```
LayoutProfit.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.list_divider_top_sides);
```

I want to change the color and the border of the layout, but that's not working if I use both the background, because it is a border OR a color then...

So how can I change the Foreground resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the layout's foreground color you can use:

```
var LayoutProfit = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LayoutProfit);
var drawable = new GradientDrawable();
drawable.SetColor(Resource.Color.colorAccent);
LayoutProfit.Foreground = drawable;
```

But if you want to set a border on this layout, you have to define a shape in `Resources/drawable/border.xml` as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
</shape>
```

Then utilize it on your layout like:

```
var LayoutProfit = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LayoutProfit);
LayoutProfit.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.border);
```